# Run timer in Swift Activity Kit without being killed

Tags: swift, swiftui

Maybe its a banal question, but I cant figure it out.

So i programmed a timer

it has a

```
// current time in widget
counter = 0

// at the first index i have a training time and at the second a pause
time = [30, 15]

// number of times, time array should be played
allSets = 3

// current number of time array being played
currentSet = 1

// current Index where i am in the time array
indexTime = 0
```

the timer looks like this:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                            
                            // executes when the counter is one
                            if (self.counter == 1) {
                                
                                // when the last entry was played of the time array and the max number of array playing has been reached
                                if (self.indexTime == 1 && self.sets == self.currentSet) {
                                    // the live activity should be stopped
                                    self.stopLiveActivity()
                                }

                                // when i was playing the last index of the array the array iteration number (currentSet) is increased
                                if (self.indexTime == 1) {
                                    self.currentSet += 1
                                }
         
                                // when the index time was 0 it increments to 1 and if it was 1 it decrements to 0
                                self.indexTime = self.indexTime == 1 ? 0 : 1
                                
                                 // the counter is updated according to new index 
                                self.counter = self.time[self.indexTime]
                            } 

                            // when the counter is greater 0 it gets decremented and my live activity gets updated
                            else if (self.counter > 0) {
                                self.counter -= 1
                                Task {
                                    await self.stopwatchActivity?.update(using: LockscreenAttributes.ContentState(elapsedTime: self.counter))
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

this code is pretty banal, my problem is that when I am on the lockscreen the execution is stopped after +- 30 seconds. In the runner I tried adding the support of live activities.

[image]

Now I think the following is my problem:

I have a folder where my app is, and a folder were the live activity is:

- App

  - update timer
- LiveActivity

maybe the update timer is killed but the live activity is left living. How could I leave my timer activity alive so that I can run the full timer when the app is in the lockscreen?

---

**Full Code:**

Timer class:

```
    import ActivityKit
import Flutter
import Foundation

class LiveActivityManager {
    
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var counter = 0
    private var duration = 0
    private var currentSet = 1
    private var indexTime = 0
    private var isPaused = false
    private var time: Array<Int> = []
    private var sets = 0
    private var stopwatchActivity: Activity<LockscreenAttributes>? = nil
    
    func startLiveActivity(data: [String: Any]?, result: FlutterResult) {
        
        let attributes = LockscreenAttributes()
        
        if let info = data as? [String: Any] {
            
            
            time = info["time"] as? Array<Int> ?? []
            sets = info["sets"] as? Int ?? 0
            counter = time[indexTime]
            
            let state = LockscreenAttributes.ContentState(elapsedTime: counter)
            
            stopwatchActivity = try? Activity<LockscreenAttributes>.request(
                attributes: attributes, contentState: state, pushType: nil)
            
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                
                if (self.counter == 1) {
                    if (self.indexTime == 1 && self.sets == self.currentSet) {
                        self.stopLiveActivity()
                    }
                    if (self.indexTime == 1) {
                        self.currentSet += 1
                    }
                    self.indexTime = self.indexTime == 1 ? 0 : 1
                    self.counter = self.time[self.indexTime]
                    
                    print("indexTime: ", self.indexTime)
                    print("currentSet: ", self.currentSet)
                    print("counter: ", self.counter)
                    print("counter according to timeArray: ", self.time[self.indexTime])
                    
                    
                } else if (self.counter > 0) {
                    self.counter -= 1
                    Task {
                        await self.stopwatchActivity?.update(using: LockscreenAttributes.ContentState(elapsedTime: self.counter))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateLiveActivity(data: [String: Any]?, result: FlutterResult) {
        if let info = data as? [String: Any] {
            
            if (info["counter"] != nil) {
                self.counter = info["counter"] as? Int ?? 0
            }
            if (info["sets"] != nil) {
                self.sets = info["sets"] as? Int ?? 0
            }
            if (info["currentSet"] != nil) {
                self.currentSet = info["currentSet"] as? Int ?? 0
            }
            if (info["indexTime"] != nil) {
                self.indexTime = info["indexTime"] as? Int ?? 0
            }
            if (info["isPaused"] != nil) {
                self.isPaused = (info["isPaused"] as? Int ?? 0) == 1
                if (self.isPaused == true) {
                    if var unwrappedTimer = timer {
                        unwrappedTimer.invalidate()
                        timer = nil
                    }
                }
                else {
                    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                                
                                // executes when the counter is one
                                if (self.counter == 1) {
                                    
                                    // when the
                                    if (self.indexTime == 1 && self.sets == self.currentSet) {
                                        self.stopLiveActivity()
                                    }
                                    if (self.indexTime == 1) {
                                        self.currentSet += 1
                                    }
                                    self.indexTime = self.indexTime == 1 ? 0 : 1
                                    self.counter = self.time[self.indexTime]
                                } else if (self.counter > 0) {
                                    self.counter -= 1
                                    Task {
                                        await self.stopwatchActivity?.update(using: LockscreenAttributes.ContentState(elapsedTime: self.counter))
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func stopLiveActivity() {
        Task {
            await stopwatchActivity?.end(using: nil, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
        }
        if let unwrappedTimer = self.timer {
            unwrappedTimer.invalidate()
            self.timer = nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Live Activity**

```
import ActivityKit
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct LockscreenAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public typealias stopwatchStatus = ContentState
    
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        var elapsedTime: Int
    }
}

struct LockscreenLiveActivity: Widget {
    
    func getTimeString(_ seconds: Int) -> String {
        let hours = seconds / 3600
        let minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60
        let seconds = (seconds % 3600) % 60
        
        return hours == 0 ?
                String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
                : String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: LockscreenAttributes.self) { context in
            // Lock screen/banner UI goes here
            HStack {
                Text("Current time ellapsed")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "timer")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                Text(getTimeString(context.state.elapsedTime))
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .activityBackgroundTint(Color.black.opacity(0.5))

        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                // Expanded UI goes here.  Compose the expanded UI through
                // various regions, like leading/trailing/center/bottom
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("StopWatchX")
                        Spacer().frame(height: 24)
                        HStack {
                            Text("Time ellapsed")
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "timer")
                            Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                            Text(getTimeString(context.state.elapsedTime))
                                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold))
                                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        }.padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
            } compactLeading: {
                Image(systemName: "timer").padding(.leading, 4)
            } compactTrailing: {
                Text(getTimeString(context.state.elapsedTime)).foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .padding(.trailing, 4)
            } minimal: {
                Image(systemName: "timer")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .padding(.all, 4)
            }
            .widgetURL(URL(string: "http://www.apple.com"))
            .keylineTint(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply can't run code that depends on a timer when your app is suspended (not in the foreground). A stopwatch isn't really a use case for live activities.

Comment: Also read [this article](https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f) for details on why a counter is not a good implementation for tracking elapsed time

Comment: If you have a start `Date` [this ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/displaying-dynamic-dates) can help.

Comment: Thanks Paul, so I guess I cant implement it like that :)